# UIAlertView does not show up from the Appdelegate

Tags: core-data, ios6, migration, uialertview

I am working on core data migration. I am trying to handle exception when the persistent stores do not match and the app crashes. But before it crashes, i would like to let the user know (through an alert view) that he needs to uninstall the app first, and the re-install it. I have the code for the alert view in persistentStoreCoordinator accessor method, but the alertview never shows up.

Here is the code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

  if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ExchangeMail.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

// Dictionary required to store the details of psc on the disk,
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL error:&error];

// This BOOL value is required to check whether a migration is required or not.
BOOL pscCompatibile = [[self managedObjectModel] isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
NSLog(@"Migration needed? %d", !pscCompatibile);


NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
[options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Non-matching Database File" message:@"The model configuration used to open the store is compatible with the one that was used to create the store. Please Uninstall the App and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[__persistentStoreCoordinator lock];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

 //        dispatch_queue_t queue = NULL;
 //        queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
 //        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
 //            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
 //            
 //            [self.myAlertView show];
 //        });

    [self.myAlertView show];
    //exit(-1);
}

[__persistentStoreCoordinator unlock];


if(!pscCompatibile){
    isMigrationRequired = YES;
}

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Comment: Crashing is not exactly how model migration is supposed to work. Is there some reason you're doing this rather than actually migrating to the new model?

Comment: One of the developers already overwrote the schema file after it was published.Hence, i am thinking if we can somehow just let the user know that the store configuration does not match, and the user needs to uninstall the app.

Comment: You never seem to set `self.myAlertView` anywhere in your code. Either do `self.myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init ...` or `show` the  `alertView` you already have created.

Comment: No version control on the data model file? No backups? You're targeting a bad user experience here, it would be really good to avoid doing so.